# Почему из $.post я не могу обратиться к внешней переменной?

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
var num = 1;
$.post("mailsender.php", data, function(data){
    num++;

})
```

В итоге ничего не происходит, тгь не увеличивается. Вопрос: как это называется и как такое избегать, если есть возможность киньте ссылки про это почитать.
Хочу сделать капчу на ajax, но из-за того, что нельзя ничего передать из $.post не получается осуществить проверку на  истинность ввода данных из капчи.
Спасибо!

Comment: Как проверяете, работает или нет?

    num++;
    alert(num);

Так тоже не работает?

Comment: Ну да алертом и проверяю, но увеличение не идёт из **$.post**
Я уже так попробывал:


    var num = 0;
    function numeric(){
          num++;
    }
    $.post("mailsender.php", data, function(data){
        numeric();
    })


Так тоже почему то не работает.
Может я где то ошибку допускаю?

Comment: В вопрос такие вещи дописывают. Это **не ответ**, ок?

По существу проверьте что callback вообще выполняется (data не пустое, адрес верный). alert туда добавьте.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так, это.... $.post - асинхронен :) Как Вы можете знать когда он отработает ? )))) 
Оно увеличивает переменную, но не факт, что это происходит ДО Вашей проверки :)

Comment: Ну да логично... блин, что же тогда придумать :/

Comment: А зачем Вам знать значение num ? Опишите задачу более детально - подскажу как лучше сделать :)

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю, [здесь](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) вы найдёте всё что вас интересует по **$.post**

Answer (score 0):

Предлагаю вариант:

передавать `num` в запросе на сервер и оттуда уже через `data` в функцию. Далее n++, затем записываем значение в какой-нибудь DOM-элемент как атрибут `value` и уже извне его считываем.